# WriteLine end of line character

Tags: xml, excel, vba, fso

I want to write rows of data from Excel to an XML file. However, I need to validate the data before I commit to file. I know that `WriteLine()` has its own end of line but I need to add it in the string. So I want to do something like this:

```
strXML = "<BOM>" & {??} _
 & "<BOM_NBR>" & p_typBomValues.strParentPNbr & "</BOM_NBR>" & {??} _
 & "<DESC>" & p_typBomValues.strParentDesc & "</DESC>" & {??} _
 & "<ECO_NBR>" & p_typBomValues.strEcoNbr & "</ECO_NBR>" & {??} _
 & "<REV>" & p_typBomValues.strRevision & "</REV>"" & {??}
 .WriteLine(strXML)
```

...not this:

```
    .WriteLine ("<BOM>")
    .WriteLine ("<BOM_NBR>" & p_typBomValues.strParentPNbr & "</BOM_NBR>")
    .WriteLine ("<DESC>" & p_typBomValues.strParentDesc & "</DESC>")
    .WriteLine ("<ECO_NBR>" & p_typBomValues.strEcoNbr & "</ECO_NBR>")
    .WriteLine ("<REV>" & p_typBomValues.strRevision & "</REV>")
```

...where {??} is the end of line character.  I've seen `Chr(10) & Chr(13)` mentioned as an option but nothing definitive.

Comment: What the "end of line character" is depends on which OS you're on.  On Windows it's typically `vbCrLf`: on Mac I think it's `vbLf`.  If you use `vbNewLine` it will use whatever is the system-appropriate one.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FSO is poorly documented about what it considers line breaks on reading and writing.  But you will probably be safe putting out either a return-and-linefeed (vbCrLf) or a bare linefeed (vbLf).  On Windows, the former is safest.

```
strXML = "<BOM>" & vbCrLf _
         & "<BOM_NBR>" & p_typBomValues.strParentPNbr & "</BOM_NBR>" & vbCrLf _
         & . . .
```

Comment: The `vbCrLf` is the answer (program is used exclusively on Windows 7).  Thanks.